# Font size with turabian-formatting

Tags: formatting, fontsize

I'm trying to wrangle some formatting/sizing issues with the `turabian-formatting`/`turabian-researchpaper` package. I've taken a look at the `.cls` and `.sty` files, but I'll admit my TeX knowledge is noob-level, at best, so I'm a bit out of my comfort zone when it comes to interpreting what's happening under the hood.

My assumption is that because the `turabian-researchpaper` package defines `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` as options, that those are the only ones that'll work (hence `13pt` returning the default). However, it also appears that `12pt` is the default (which is backed up by the package documentation) which is where my confusion comes in, as specifying `12pt` yields much larger text than when not specifying any size. Please see the sample file content below to see exactly what I'm running.

Is there some arcane detail I'm lacking context on that perfectly explains what I'm seeing? I've confirmed I'm running the 2021-03-20 version.

```latex
% This file is run with "latexmk -bibtex -pdflua test.tex"

\documentclass[turabian-researchpaper]{report}
% \documentclass[turabian-researchpaper,10pt]{report} % same as when unspecified
% \documentclass[turabian-researchpaper,11pt]{report} % slightly larger
% \documentclass[turabian-researchpaper,12pt]{report} % larger still
% \documentclass[turabian-researchpaper,13pt]{report} % back to the original size

\usepackage{turabian-formatting}
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[style=canadian]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't check it but I presume the default font size as specified in the manual is only in effect with `\documentclass{turabian-researchpaper}` and _not_ with `\documentclass[turabian-researchpaper]{report}`.

Comment: Furthermore it says it the package documentation in the changelog that "Loading turabian-formatting as a package is no longer supported." since 2016.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I've submitted an answer and mentioned you by name, but I don't know how to give you credit for the answer in a way that impacts upvotes/scoring. In any case, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marijn's reply above, I was able to resolve this. I don't understand *why* it resulted in the behaviour in my original question, but it's at least consistent now that I'm using the updated markup. What's considered 12pt font feels too large to me, but that's its own thing and may be entirely subjective. In any case, it serves me right for trying to cobble things together from (outdated) snippets I found online. In case someone in the future needs this, the updated definition is as follows:

```latex
% This file is run with "latexmk -bibtex -pdflua test.tex"

\documentclass{turabian-researchpaper}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[style=canadian]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
\end{document}
```